# i create project in django & when I try to run program it shows error of invalid interpreter selected for the project

Tags: python, django

And after adding a valid interpreter it again shows the error.
it was a previously made project and was working without any issue but now it is not working. #help THANK YOU IN ADVANCE.

ERRORS:
jobs.Job.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow or run command "pip install Pillow".

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\portfolio>pip install pillow;
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (8.
2.0)

Comment: "adding a valid interpreter" to where? Are you sure you are using the same Python 3.9 interpreter that you installed the Pillow in?

Answer (score 1):

This might be happening because you have two different versions of Python installed in your system. I would recommend uninstalling one of them.
Or you can remove the path of the old Python version from the environment variable.

Comment: I checked whether there is 2 diff version but was not found. i have installed only one python.

Comment: are you running the project in a virtual environment?

Comment: yes,i create it from pycharm so it is.

Comment: make sure that your python environment is active while installing the pillow.